# How to pass data as parameters into the function declared outside the ng-repeat table?

Tags: angularjs

Iam working flights list application.here I need to call a function onclick of join group button.In that function,I need to pass parameters as the data used in ng-repeat declared in row of a table.But Iam unable to access the ng-repeat data declared in row as function is declared outside the ng-repeat row.How can I pass that data into the function?

```
<table ng-repeat="flight in dArray.trips.tripOption" style="border:1px solid white;padding:5px">
                <tr ng-repeat="data in flight.slice">
                    <td>{{flight.saleTotal}}</td>
                    <td style="color:red">{{data.duration}}</td>
                    <td ng-repeat="data1 in data.segment">
                        <table>
                            <tr ng-repeat="data2 in data1.leg">
                                <td style="color:white">{{data2.origin}}
                                    <br><span style="color:white">{{data2.departureTime}}</span></td>
                                <td style="color:black">{{data2.destination}}
                                    <br><span style="color:white">{{data2.arrivalTime}}</span></td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <button  ng-click="joinTheGrp(data2.arrivalTime)">Join Group</button>
                    </td>
                </tr>

            </table>
```

Comment: Well you have access to the data in the controller don't you? Why not just call the function as you do, and simply access in the controller where the method will be anyway?

Comment: Iam using google api for getting data.Iam displaying particular data that i needed by using ng-repeat and I want that exact data repeated in the td onclick of button.so i need to send that data in function to access in the controller.

Answer (score 0):

Put the button inside the table it's working

```
<table>
  <tr ng-repeat="data2 in data1.leg">
    <td style="color:white">
      {{data2.origin}}
      <br>
      <span style="color:white">{{data2.departureTime}}</span>
    </td>
    <td style="color:black">
      {{data2.destination}}
      <br>
      <span style="color:white">{{data2.arrivalTime}}</span>
    </td>
    <td>
      <button ng-click="joinTheGrp(data2.arrivalTime)">Join Group</button>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: But then that adds a button to each row. Is that what the OP wants?

Comment: I have to display the button after the data has been displayed.so it has to be placed in td only.

Comment: which arrivaltime you need?

Answer (score 0):

You have to push required nested array to your angular controller, Below code shows you how to do that, i am not using tables here, but this is exactly how you do it.

```js
angular.module('selectExample', [])
      .controller('ExampleController', ['$scope',
        function($scope) {
          $scope.data1 = {};
          $scope.data1.leg = [
            {
              'departureTime': '123',
              'arrivalTime': '123' 
            },
            {
              'departureTime': '234',
              'arrivalTime': '234' 
            },
            {
              'departureTime': '345',
              'arrivalTime': '345' 
            }
          ];
          $scope.joinTheGrp = function (arrTime) {
            alert(arrTime);
          }
        }
      ]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="selectExample">
<div ng-controller="ExampleController">
    <span ng-repeat="data2 in $parent.groups = (data1.leg | filter:q)">
      <p>Arrival time: {{data2.arrivalTime}}</p>
      <p>Departure time: {{data2.departureTime}}</p>
    </span>
    <span ng-repeat="group in groups">
      <button ng-click="joinTheGrp(group.arrivalTime)">Arrival Time</button>
    </span>
  </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code you have this line:

```
<table ng-repeat="flight in dArray.trips.tripOption"
```

So, in your controller, you have access to dArray and following your template I assume your expected data structure looks like this:

```
dArray.trips.tripOption.slice.segment.leg
```

Your button appears to be on the dArray.trips.tripOption.slice object, so any segment.leg beneath it is going to be the data you're interested in. So your template can change slightly:

```
<tr ng-repeat="data in flight.slice track by $index">
```

And your button method can change:

```
<button ng-click="joinTheGrp($index)">
```

The method on your controller with some getters to make life easier:

```
getMyDArray() {
  // Do your google api call in the $onInit() of your controller then
  // return it here;
  return dArray;
}

getMyArrayDataSlice(index) {
  const dataArray = this.getMyDArray();
  return dataArray.trips.tripOptions.slice[index];
}

joinTheGrp(index) {
  const data = this.getMyArrayDataSlice(index);

  // Now you can work on 'data' as though it were the one line
  // where your button resides;
}
```

Comment: while trying with this code getMyArray() is not a function error is being appeared.what to do now?

Answer (score 0):

Can't you use indexes to access the data you need. For example if you need `data2.arrivalTime` value you can access it outside ng-repeat like this.

```
data.segment[1].leg[1].arrivalTime
```

Indexes for the arrays must be known here, which raises the question since you are outside ng-repeat, which value you are trying to pass into the method? Is it the last value that get assigned at the end of both loops?

Or else you could repeat the same loop

```
<div ng-repeat="data1 in data.segment">
  <div ng-repeat="data2 in data1.leg">
    <td>
      <button  ng-click="joinTheGrp(data2.arrivalTime)">Join Group</button>
   </td>
  </div>
</div>
```